# Make small radius for circle in drawable

Tags: android, image, svg, vector, android-drawable

I try to make some animation with Android vector drawable, but I don't how I can change the radius of the circle. So, there is my path:

```
<path
        android:fillAlpha="0.039624095"
        android:fillColor="#C2C2C2"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M58.75,58.75m-57.75,0a57.75,57.75 0,1 1,115.5 0a57.75,57.75 0,1 1,-115.5 0"
        android:strokeWidth="1.5"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.4953012"
        android:strokeColor="#3A48C1" />
```

How i can do this?

Comment: put it in a group and scale the group.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [AnimatedVectorDrawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable).